# QtWeb compiling error on Windows

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, qt4

i get a package named QtWeb ( http://qtweb.net ) and i compiling it on linux, and all is ok.
But when i try to compiling on windows with QT 4.8.5 and MINGW, generate a lot of similar  message :

```
src\certificateinfo.h:40: error: 'QSslCertificate' was not declared in this scope
     void setCertificateChain(const QList<QSslCertificate> &chain);
                                          ^
```

The correspondent files is certificateinfo.cpp ( http://pastebin.com/PHGMM3FJ ) and certificateinfo.h ( http://pastebin.com/YKZsZ93v ).

Some idea how to fix it ?

Comment: Please put inline content in here. Show the path please where QSslCertificate is located. Also, it is mixing up different include styles.

Comment: 'QSslCertificate' is located in 'C:\Qt\4.8.5\include\QtNetwork'

Comment: Can you show the output make VERBOSE=1?